# if one linear operator of a set of linear operators sends a vector to zero then the product of linear operators must send the vector to zero?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

This question is related to linear algebra.

Suppose we have a finite set of linear operators called $T$:

$T= \{ T_1, T_2, T_3, ...,T_k \}$

How can I prove the following claim?

$\exists T_i \in T \; such \; that \; (T_i) \alpha=0 \implies (T_1T_2...T_k) \alpha=0 $

I mean if there exists some linear operator that sends a vector to zero then the multiplication of all linear operators also sends the vector to zero.

---------------------------------------------MY EDIT-------------------------------------------

I ask this question because I saw something like this in a linear algebra book. I state what was exactly in the book:

Let $T$ be a diagonizable linear operator and let $c_1,...,c_k$ be the distinct characteristic values of $T$. Then it is easy to see that the minimal polynomial fot $T$ is the polynomial
$$p=(x-c_1)...(x-c_k).$$
If $\alpha$ is a characteristic vector, then one of the operators $T-c_1I,...,T-c_kI$ sends $\alpha$ into $0$. Therefore
$$(T-c_1I)...(T-c_kI)\alpha=0$$
for every characteristic vector $\alpha$.

Please explain if I asked the wong question and explain why the last claim is true i.e. $(T-c_1I)...(T-c_kI)\alpha=0$
for every characteristic vector $\alpha$.

Answer (score 2):

This is false.  For instance, consider $T_1=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$, $T_2=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$, and $\alpha=(0,1)$.  Then $T_1\alpha=0$ but $T_1T_2\alpha=T_1(1,0)=(1,0)$.

Comment: you are right. I added something to my question. Could you please consider that?